# How to fix a broken limb

Tags: trees, damage, pruning

I have a peach tree that was weighted down with fruit this summer, so much so that the branch split.  The split is beyond repair, and I'm now chiefly concerned with the health of the tree.

I cut the branch off (with a chainsaw) a healthy distance from the trunk, where one would ordinarily prune it, but now what should I do, if anything to the remaining branch that is still split?

Does anyone suggest:

1. gluing the split back to the trunk
2. using a fastener, such as a screw
3. not attempting to re-attach the wood but covering the "wound" with something
4. ...

I like to think nature is resilient, but this is right on the trunk, and nature is resilient enough to plant another peach tree -- something I would rather not do if I want to keep getting amazing peaches.

-- Edit 10/7/2015 --

Pictures, added, per request.

[image]

[image]

Comment: pictures please

Comment: They're used to hard pruning. If the crack goes more than 1/4 of the way through, I'd say take it off... But I'd like to know the length/diameter of this branch before I say anything

Comment: I'll do my best to take a picture this evening and post it -- thanks.

Comment: @kevinsky -- per your suggestion, pictures added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have an affection for this tree that goes beyond it being a good fruit bearer I would plant another one now.  By the time it's ready to fruit this one should be done.

This tree has a poor structure and I believe I can see [included bark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_fork) which indicates another future weakness.

Yes, you can repair the split with thin threaded aircraft quality stainless steel bolts that don't rust easily.  Two bolts at four to six inch spacing with a washer on the end with the nut. Don't try and tighten this too much.

Do not use wound paint. This is counterproductive and can cause more damage.